# Inequalities giving incorrect solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, rational-numbers, integral-inequality

**Question**:

> Find the solution set for:$$\frac{|x|-1}{|x|-2} \geq 0$$ $x\not=\pm2$

---

**My attempt**:

Let $|x| = y$, then inequality becomes $(y-1)(y-2)>=0$

Implies that:

---

#### #1. $y-1\geq0$ and $y-2\geq0$

Then, $y\geq1$ and $y\geq2$, which means $y\geq2$.

Substituting, $|x|=y$, it becomes: $x\geq2$ and $x\leq-2 \Rightarrow$ $2\leq x \leq -2$

---

#### #2. $y-1<0$ and $y-2<0$

Then,  $y<1$ and $y<2$, which means $y<2$

Substituting, $|x|=y$, it becomes: $x<2$ and $x>-2$. $\Rightarrow -2 < x < 2$

---

As it can be seen, **#1** is definitely false, so answer is:

$$x \in (-2,2)$$

But the answer given in my textbook is $x \in (-\infty, -2)\cup(-1,1)\cup(2,\infty)$

I need help regarding where I did go wrong.

Comment: There is something wrong in "$ x≥2$ and $x≤−2⇒ 2≤x≤−2$". Actually, it $x<-2$ **or** $x>2$. Same error below. And if you have both $y<1$ and $y<2$, notice that $y<1$ (it's governed by "more constrained")

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Could you please tell what is the mistake there ?

Comment: A number can't be at the same time $\leq-2$ and $\geq2$, but that's what you write. And actually, this is not what the condition $|x|\geq2$ means. You confuse the meaning of *and* & *or*, and it's why you write nonsense subsequently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mix different notions of "and".
In case 1, $x$ is a solution if $|x|> 2$ (becasue $|x|=2$ is forbidden anyway), that is, $x$ is a solution if $x>2$, and $x$ is also a solution if $x<-2$. That is different from saying that $x$ is a solution in the rare occasions where both $x>2$ and $x<-2$. So you should find "$x>2$ or $x<-2$" instead of the contradictory $2<x<-2$.

In case 2 note that a number $y$ that is both $<1$ and $<2$ is best described as a number $<1$. (Yes, "**if** $y<1$ and $y<2$, **then** $y<2$", but we should look for "if and only if" to precisely determine all solutions).

Comment: Ok, I got it. The problem arose due to my thinking $|x|>a\Rightarrow x<-a$ *and* $x>a$, which is wrong. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two cases :

$1)$   $x \geq 0 \implies |x|=x:$
$$\frac{x-1}{x-2} \geq 0$$
Solution set would be, $x\geq1$ and $x>2$ or $x\leq1$ and $x<2$.
$$x \in (2,\infty) \cup (-\infty,1]$$

$2)$  $x\leq0 \implies |x|=-x:$
$$\frac{x+1}{x+2} \geq 0$$
Solution set would be, $x\geq-1$ and $x>-2$ or $x\leq-1$ and $x<-2$.
$$x \in [-1,\infty) \cup (-\infty,-2)$$

So taking the common solution from the two cases we get:
$$x \in (-\infty,-2) \cup [-1,1] \cup (2,\infty)$$

Comment: Ok, I got it. The problem arose due to my thinking |x|>a⇒x<−a and x>a, which is wrong. Thanks for showing the steps.